# Telnet client in go

Tags: go, telnet

I am trying to send 'hello world' to the telnet server from go client. In the [documentation](https://godoc.org/github.com/reiver/go-telnet) I have found example:

```
var caller telnet.Caller = telnet.StandardCaller    
telnet.DialToAndCall("localhost:5555", caller)
```

What is the next step to send 'helloworld' now?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Example of programmatic connection using [go-telnet](https://godoc.org/github.com/reiver/go-telnet)

```
func SetTest() {
    conn, _ := telnet.DialTo("localhost:5555")
    conn.Write([]byte("hello world"))
    conn.Write([]byte("\n"))

}
```

Answer (score 4):

In the example below you can see that the CallTELNET uses stdin and stdout to allow the user of the program to communicate through telnet. You can send "hello world" by running the program and typing the desired text you wish to send followed by the enter key.

package main

```
import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"

    "github.com/reiver/go-oi"
    "github.com/reiver/go-telnet"
)

type caller struct{}

func (c caller) CallTELNET(ctx telnet.Context, w telnet.Writer, r telnet.Reader) {
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        oi.LongWrite(w, scanner.Bytes())
        oi.LongWrite(w, []byte("\n"))
    }
}

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("Dial to %s:%d\n", "localhost", 8080)
    err := telnet.DialToAndCall(fmt.Sprintf("%s:%d", "localhost", 8080), caller{})

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

Examples found [here](https://systembash.com/a-simple-go-tcp-server-and-tcp-client/) and [here](https://gitlab.com/tyabuta/go-simple-telnet)

Answer (score 2):

The telnet library implements the 'Writer' type. The [Writer Type](https://godoc.org/github.com/reiver/go-telnet#Writer) has a `Write` method.